# iOS: How to discover power usage of each running app?

Tags: ios, api, process, battery

I'm very confused about an app I've found on the App Store called [Battery Doctor](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/battery-doctor-master-battery/id446751279?mt=8).

In this app there is a feature called Power Usage where it lists all of your apps (and system apps) and how much power each app burns. See the image below.

[image]

The list of running processes can be retrieved from the OS, but I cannot find any way to discover the power usage of any apps. The "Unknown" for some entries seems to imply it tries to query for these values and for some apps it is unable to obtain the data. It is also able to distinguish whether an app is current in use or not in use. But most important to me is the battery usage itself. How is this trickery done?

Comment: have u achieved what u r searching ?

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741391/how-to-get-battery-consumption-value-for-an-ios-app-x-mah-min

Answer (score 0):

After doing some tests, over a couple of days, I have a VERY strong suspicion that these numbers we see are NOT actual measurements on the device, they seem WAY too constant, and only some of the actually running apps are on the list...

I have a THEORY that they have some sort of limited database, and if any app on the phone is matching this list, it is included.

It could still be useful as a hint on what uses a lot, and what uses a little. But I do not think you should see it as 'real' numbers from your phone. Can anyone confirm or disprove this theory???

**That also explains why you can't find a method to get this info**

There are also TWO almost identical apps one with a orange and one with a green battery icon, And it seems to be the same apps that are included and excluded. that seems a bit fishy too... There is a third app "Battery Lite", that are similar but without mAh/min readings (strange unit btw)